# How to judge only one class classification(e.g. Dog or other) in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'd just like to judge whether image is Dog or not by Keras.
I use Image for Keras as Input, and I expect Output is confidence of 0.0 ~ 1.0.
Before asking in here, I understood there was some hint.

1. I can define threshold for confidence which is judged by my learned model.

   - e.g. confidence <= 0.9 of my defined threshold. If confidence is between 0.9 and 1.0, it is Dog.
2. I used last Activation is softmax and loss function for compile is categorical_crossentropy. But I found combination of sigmoid and binary_crossentropy looks good.

I understand I need Dog images as train data to learn Dog.
But for other, how can I make it? To learn not Dog, do I need to prepare image of Cat, Human, Car, Tree and etc?
In that case, for learning "Other" case, I need a lot of type of images. That's  Car, Human etc.

How about my understanding? I would like to hear good idea. Thanks.

Comment: since you have a binary classification I would suggest to use a sigmoid at the last layer and binary crossentropy. this is the gold standard for binary classifications

Answer (score 1):

I think the understanding in general is correct albeit it misses a some details. There are also alternatives to what you are proposing. For instance, you don't necessarily need a confidence level, you could just get the class (dog/non-dog) that has the highest probability, or you can even compare the probabilities making sure there is a big difference between them. If you don't use softmax you could have a case in which the outputs are 0.91 and 0.95, so pay attention.

In regards to the data, you need to include a large variety of both dogs and non-dogs objects, and pay attention to the data you are feeding: some times the networks are biased by the colors. For instance, let's say you feed the network with dogs that are mainly black and brown. If your network detects blue color it might think it's not a dog. Same thing can happen with the background: if all your dog pictures have a similar background (let's say grass), if you input a dog in the snow it might not work.

In addition, you can also think in other ways to make your network pay attention to some dog features. In theory, a good model with sufficiently data and time to train might become a good classifier, but you can also do a bit of feature engineering and feed the network with a specific types of inputs. For instance, you can control that you want 100 pictures of each dog breed, or some pictures focused on the paws, other pictures where you can see the tail, etc.

The description of your problem is very general.

Comment: Very clarifying comment bro! Thanks to you explanation about this subject, I just changed my approach about a classification problem using CNN, and the accuracy of the network is now more high than ever!